# An elegant way to mock creation of AsyncTasks and Intents in Android code

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have an Android activity, in which there are calls like

```
final ConnectToServerAsyncTask task = new ConnectToServerAsyncTask(...);
```

and

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
```

In order to unit test this class, I need to be able to mock the creation of `ConnectToServerAsyncTask` and `Intent` (e. g. using Mockito).

Are there more elegant methods than the one described below?

```
public class MainActivityOfTheApp extends Activity {
    private IAsyncTaskFactory asyncTaskFactory = new AsyncTaskFactory();
    private IIntentFactory intentFactory = new IntentFactory();

    public void setAsyncTaskFactory(final IAsyncTaskFactory aFactory)
    {
        asyncTaskFactory = aFactory;
    }

    public void setIntentFactory(final IIntentFactory aFactory)
    {
        intentFactory = aFactory;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        ...
        final ConnectToServerAsyncTask task = asyncTaskFactory.create(...);
        ...

        final Intent intent = intentFactory.create(this, OtherActivity.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

In a unit test, I would create an instance of MainActivityOfTheApp and then inject mocks using `setAsyncTaskFactory` and `setIntentFactory`.

Comment: Your solution is also the most clever that I can think of. I, too, would very much like to know if there is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

### PowerMock

You can mock constructors using [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13#How_to_mock_construction_of_new_objects).

So in your case the test would look like something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MainActivityOfTheApp.class)
public class MainActivityOfTheAppTest{
  private AsyncTaskFactory asyncTaskFactory;
  private IntentFactory intentFactory;
  private MainActivityOfTheApp mainActivityOfTheApp;

  @Before
  public void prepare() {
    asyncTaskFactory = PowerMockito.mock(AsyncTaskFactory.class);
    intentFactory = PowerMockito.mock(IntentFactory.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(AsyncTaskFactory.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(asyncTaskFactory);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(IntentFactory.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(intentFactory);
    mainActivityOfTheApp = new MainActivityOfTheApp();
  }

  @Test
  public void doTest() {
    //mainActivityOfTheApp has the mocks in final field inside, no need for the setters.
  }
}
```

I have to note, that PowerMock is powerful, but often has problems with complicated classloading (for example OSGI environments), or code coverage tools (jacoco for example). It works usually, but I have wasted some time with it.

### Without PowerMock

Second possibility is to create [package private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)(No modifier. Why not protected or public? See [What's wrong with overridable method calls in constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/337621)) methods, which call the constructor like this:

```
public class MainActivityOfTheApp extends Activity {
    private final IAsyncTaskFactory asyncTaskFactory = constructAsyncTaskFactory();
    private final IIntentFactory intentFactory = constructIntentFactory();

    IAsyncTaskFactory constructAsyncTaskFactory()
    {
        return new AsyncTaskFactory();
    }

    IIntentFactory constructIntentFactory()
    {
        return new IntentFactory();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your unit test (the test must be in the same package as the tested class!) you override the construct*() methods:

```
public class MainActivityOfTheAppTest{
  private AsyncTaskFactory asyncTaskFactory;
  private IntentFactory intentFactory;
  private MainActivityOfTheApp mainActivityOfTheApp;

  @Before
  public void prepare() {
    asyncTaskFactory = mock(AsyncTaskFactory.class);
    intentFactory = mock(IntentFactory.class);
    mainActivityOfTheApp = new HackedMainActivityOfTheApp();
  }

  @Test
  public void doTest() {
    //mainActivityOfTheApp has the mocks in final field inside, no need for the setters.
  }

  private class HackedMainActivityOfTheApp extends MainActivityOfTheApp {
        IAsyncTaskFactory constructAsyncTaskFactory()
        {
            return asyncTaskFactory;
        }

        IIntentFactory constructIntentFactory()
        {
            return intentFactory;
        }
  }
}
```

You can protect the construct* methods if you sign the jar containing the MainActivityOfTheApp. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/968612/337621 :

> Also, patches are harder (you have to re-sign the jar), class-patches are impossible (all classes in a single package must have the same signature source) and splitting jars becomes a chore.